# Disable Ipv4 and use Ipv6 only on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, ipv6, ipv4

My raspberry pi has an ipv4 and ipv6. please is there a way it could only use ipv6 and disable the ipv4 totally, could I then forward the ipv6 port 22 interaction to a port 22 on another device. please help

Comment: How're you getting ipv6? If you're tunneling, you might not be able to do it totally but you could throw in some clever firewall rules.

Comment: my Isp works with both. Please if you cold be specific, what rules could I use.

Answer (score 0):

To disable IPv4, edit your /etc/dhcpcd.conf file and add the line:

```
ipv6only
```